# Can't import pyinputplus module

Tags: python, pyinputplus

When I try to import the module on Mu, I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'`

However, on command prompt it says its successfully installed. Im on windows 10 and using python 3.9. any help appreciated

Comment: Are you using any kind of virtualenv or conda env?

Comment: no im not using it

Comment: 64 bit Python / 32 bit Python? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using 64 bit python and using Mu

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install that module in your computer.
By using:

```
pip install pyinputplus
```

Then, you can import it by:

```
import pyinputplus as pyip
```

and then, you will get results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptjqa.png).